# How to run a Powershell script with Rename-Computer in it using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, runspace

I need to run a Powershell Script using C# with "Rename-Computer" in it on a Windows 2016 Server.

The Problem is that it is not working or executing correctly.
The remote Computer doesn't get renamed and also not in the AD.
When Executing there are no Errors. Only thing i know is that ps.HadErrors is true.

When I run the script nothing happens.

Expected Result would be the renamed Computer

[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result is that the computername stays the same as before
[image: Actual Result]

I already tried executing the Powershell Script on the Windows Server and it worked as it is supposed to. I also tried Executing a other Powershell Script in C# that is writing to a File and it worked. Another thing i tried is to add the Module and the Command to Runspace, but it also did not change anything.

This is the Code i tried:

```
    public static readonly string script = $@"

    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString ""passwort"" -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(""Administrator"", $password)
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName ""Computer01"" -NewName ""NewComputer01"" -DomainCredential 
    $credential -Force";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
            rs.Open();
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = rs;
            ps.AddScript(script);
            ps.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help and everything is clear.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: So you you please clarify what is not working, what errors do you get, whats happening when you run the script? etc.

Comment: Ok sorry for being unclear. I thought i have mentionend all.
I hope now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I used an .Net Core Application so I had to use Powershell Core. Somehow it cannot make the WMI Connection when using Powershell Core, but it worked with Windows Powershell. So I had to reconfigure WMI on the Windows 10 Client and it worked!